# Javascript animation picture rotation

Tags: javascript

I have two simple functions that I am trying to use to create a swinging motion with. I am fairly new to javascript and need a little direction to achieve my goal.

the first function is :

```
function up() {
imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.transform = 'rotate(45deg)');
```

// this creates the upward swinging motion that i am looking for.

```
function down()` {
```

`imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.transform = 'rotate(27deg)');
// this creates the return back to original state that i want.

I can get both functions to perform separately on their own, but I need to be able to call both functions in a manner like:

```
up(); 
 down()//after .5sec
 up()//.5sec after down() call
and down()// .5sec after previous up() call
```

.

I have been using the setTimeout(function,timedelay) to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create the timer in `onLoad`:

```
<body onLoad="setTimeout(changeDirection(),500)">
```

At the start of your `<script>` add

```
var direction = 0;
```

Then create `changeDirection()`:

```
function changeDirection(){
if(direction==0)
  {up();direction=1;}
  else
  {down();direction=0;}
}
```

Comment: This did not work.  It calls both functions simultaneously and they cancel each movement out, making element look stationary.  When i changed the Timeout to 1000, it made element rotate up, but subsequently did not rotate back down to original state.

Comment: I have tried this method as well to no avail.  I am trying to fire off this sequence on a submit button.  This still does not allow the motion to render.  I have another function assigned to the submit button as well that produces a sound and it is firing off without a hitch.